# How to drink water on Mars?

Tags: spacex, mars, physics, water, pressure

There are craters filled with water on Mars as shown below. If fresh water is found, how would astronauts drink the water? Can the Apollo a spacesuit food/drink port be used to equalize the pressure in the container of water and drink it with a straw?

Going back to the ship is not an option to get hydrated.

[image]
[image]
www.hq.nasa.gov

[image]
astronomy.com

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/29361/would-drinking-melted-ice-water-from-mars-taste-like-sparkling-water

[How to get water inside a space suit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33882/how-to-get-water-inside-a-space-suit)

Comment: I could be wrong, but isn't that crater filled with CO2-- not water? Or even a CO2 and H2O mix? I think it'd kill you to drink.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Carbonated water/ice is what it is.

Comment: Note that water literally can't exist in liquid form on Mars' surface, due to the low atmospheric pressure. It's only in solid or gaseous form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nobody is going to drink the water on Mars directly. It has to be [filtered](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12135/is-water-on-mars-the-same-as-earth-water) first.

On the Apollo spacesuits, [food and drink was carried internally.](http://www.collectspace.com/ubb/Forum29/HTML/000794.html) The port was for emergencies only.

> The moonwalkers from Apollo 13 onwards had a drink bag installed inside the suit which allowed them to drink when wearing the pressure suit on the Moon. Shepard and Mitchell were the first to use this device on the Moon.
>
> From Apollo 15 onwards the moonwalkers also had a high energy foodstick which was located in a little bag velcroed to the suit inside the neck rim.

Comment: @Muze Just think. If water or ice is from atmospheric origin, could it contain any salt? What happens if salty water is evaporated? Is there any salty water vapor?

Comment: Should the ice in the picture be discolored from particulates from an even mix of salt and red dust?

Comment: @Muze that's an interesting point to consider. Water that has condensed from the atmosphere when the weather is calm may form a layer that is *fairly clean*, but there's no reason to think it's potable. I don't know if the fresh ice forms molecule by molecule directly from atmospheric water, or if there is any micro-condensation on particulates or other things in the atmosphere first. That would require some significant atmospheric modeling. That might be a good question to raise as a separate question.

Comment: @uhoh https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/29363/how-salty-is-the-air-on-mars